# VTKOutlineGlowPass afterimage problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, vtk

I'm trying to implement 'vtkOutlineGlowPass' to highlight selected objects.
The project uses winform + vtk.

There are two renderers.

1. Main renderer. Initially placed inside renderWindow.
2. created a new one. This is where I create actors for the outline.
   1,2 are added to the same renderWindow.Used function VtkRenderWindow.AddRenderer().

- called render() from the vtkRenderWindow to refresh the screen when there's visual changes on the screen.

Situation 1.

this happens when I get the camera from the main renderer and set it to the sub renderer.

[image]

Situation 2.

this happens when I don't

[image]

I hope the outlineGlowPass image to only emphasize the outline of the actors. But I don't seem to find any clear solution. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void renderWindowControl1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //.. renderWindowControl Init codes


    foreach (var actor in actors)
    {
        renderer.AddActor(actor);                               //add actors inside main renderer
    }

    #region outlineGlowPass Init
    var renWin = renderWindowControl1.RenderWindow;            

    rendererOutline = vtkRenderer.New();                        //create a second renderer. This is where actors for outlines will be put
    rendererOutline.SetLayer(1);                                //call setLayer(1) to make the second renderer's background transparent. 
    renWin.SetNumberOfLayers(2);                            
    renWin.AddRenderer(rendererOutline);

    var basicPasses = vtkRenderStepsPass.New();
    var glowPass = vtkOutlineGlowPass.New();                    //create render pass.
    glowPass.SetDelegatePass(basicPasses);

    rendererOutline.SetPass(glowPass);                          //apply render pass to highlight renderer.

    foreach (var outlineActor in outlineActors)
    {
        rendererOutline.AddActor(outlineActor);                 //add actors for the outline to the second renderer.
    }

    renderer.GradientBackgroundOn();
    renderer.SetBackground(0.5, 0.5, 0.2);
    renderer.SetBackground2(0.2, 0.1, 0.9);
    renderer.ResetCamera();

    var camera = renderer.GetActiveCamera();                    //get the camera from the first renderer and apply it to the second one. (situation1)
    renderer.ResetCamera();
    rendererOutline.SetActiveCamera(camera);

    renderWindow.Render();

    #endregion
}
```

```
private void add_Actor(vtkPolyDataAlgorithm algo, double[] position, double[] scale, double[] rgb)
{
    #region create MainActors
    vtkPolyDataMapper mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
    string className = algo.GetClassName();
    mapper.SetInputConnection(algo.GetOutputPort());

    vtkActor actor = vtkActor.New();                                            //액터
    //setting actor status..(scale, pos, etc)

    actors.Add(actor);          // keep inside member variable(container).
                                // once renderer's init is done, it will be put inside the main renderer.
    #endregion

    #region create outlineActors
    mapper.SetInputConnection(algo.GetOutputPort());

    var mapperOutline = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
    mapperOutline.SetInputConnection(algo.GetOutputPort());

    var actorOutline = vtkActor.New();
    actorOutline.SetMapper(mapperOutline);
    actorOutline.SetPosition(position[0], position[1], position[2]);
    actorOutline.SetScale(scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);                //inherit status of original actors that are inside the main renderer.

    var outlineProperty = actorOutline.GetProperty();
    outlineProperty.SetColor(0.5,0.5,0.0);
    outlineProperty.LightingOff();

    outlineActors.Add(actorOutline);     // also keeps the actors temporaily inside container.
                                         // once renderer's init is done, it will be put inside the sub renderer.
    #endregion
}
```

I wanted to render a highlight outline for the actor. Of course the outline should remain its original shape.